# Migrate to Jetpack compose error: Unbound symbols not allowed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, kotlin-android-extensions, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to **migrate my existing project to partially use Jetpack compose** for it.
So I opened it using **Android studio 4.2-canary9** and added a compose activity so that Android studio adds needed configurations needed.

When I tried to run the project it gave me an error:

```
e: java.lang.AssertionError: Unbound symbols not allowed
```

Using `Run with --stacktrace` I have this stacktrace thrown at me:

```
e: java.lang.AssertionError: Unbound symbols not allowed
    Unbound public symbol for public kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main/state.<get-state>|-5663767092261428579[0]
    Unbound public symbol for public kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main/stateContainer.<get-stateContainer>|-4335442114828357571[0]
    Unbound public symbol for public kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main/list.<get-list>|9139041782698166288[0]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFiles(JvmBackendFacade.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:616)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:203)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:346)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:240)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:601)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The first route mentions `activity_main` which is an activity not made using compose. It refers to **Kotlin android extensions** which is used to replace `findViewById` (`state` is a TextView ID)

```
Unbound public symbol for public kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main/state.<get-state>|-5663767092261428579[0]
```

Here are some configurations:

- **compose**: 1.0.0-alpha02 & 1.0.0-alpha04
- **kotlin**: 1.4.0 & 1.4.10
- **android-gradle-plugin**: 4.2.0-alpha09 & 4.2.0-alpha13
- **kotlin-stdlib**: either jdk8 and jdk7

Thanks in advance

Comment: HI, did u manage to fix this?

Comment: Hey. Nope, still having this issue on the project.

Comment: @Jonathan Appearently this is fixed and will be shipped with Kotlin 1.4.20 ([Link](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pull/3726))

Comment: Any idea when it will be released?

Comment: It is expected to be released soon ([1.4.20 kotlin tag](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/build-1.4.20-M2-158))

Comment: anyone tried to upgrade kotlin version to `1.4.20` to check if this error is solved?

Comment: @DavidIbrahim I did... It leads to another issue. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43350

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. As a workaround, I replaced all Kotlin synthetic with ViewBinding. After I did it everything worked.

Comment: SO kotlin synthetics cant work along wit jetpack compose?

Comment: Even `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in build.gradle is causing issue. Totally removing it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, this issue has been fixed and will be shipped to **Kotlin:`1.4.20`** (Which is not released at the time)

[**Google issue tracker reference**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166927559)

[**Kotlin Pull request**](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/pull/3726)

**[Update at 27 Nov]**

Updating to `1.4.20` leads to another error [**[Ref](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43350)**]

Comment: composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.20'
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.0-alpha04'
    }
After updating the Kotlin compiler to 1.4.20, I get this error
'could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.4.20'

Comment: Unfortunately `1.4.20` is not released yet. It's a promise that it will be fixed in that version. Checkout [kotlin releases](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases) for detail.

Comment: this works but `1.4.20` causes this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43350. so...

Comment: @guness Yup... Tried `1.4.20` myself. Didn't work. You're right

Comment: True story, updating to 1.4.20 lead to the above error described by Mahdi-Malv

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was migrating a template project. What fixed it for me was deleting some template code that accessed elements that were grabbed by findbyviewid.

Comment: Any code in the default views that was created that referenced views directly. For example any code that used findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

I have to choose the other way around for this case,

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.1.0-beta03"
}
```

I also have to downgrade the Kotlin version for this.

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
ext.compose_version = '1.1.1'
```