# android jetpack compose kotlin synthetic extension support

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, synthetic

I'm getting Unbound symbols not allowed compiler error during integration compose to a big project. It seems it doesn't support synthetic extentions. Is there a way to use compose with synthetic extentions? My project is too big to migrate at once and heavily use synthetic extentions. If not do you know that is there a plan for support this soon? Thanks in advance.

```
e: java.lang.AssertionError: Unbound symbols not allowed
    Unbound public symbol for public kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_normal/txt.<get-txt>|-845173590652748007[0]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate to Jetpack compose error: Unbound symbols not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63788205/migrate-to-jetpack-compose-error-unbound-symbols-not-allowed)

Comment: Nope, it says remove all kotlinx synthetic extentions, which is really difficult for huge projects. My question is that is there a way to use them both at the same time in a project?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: Replace synthetics with viewbinding

Comment: replacing existing synthetic binding is not an option for now for me, looking for a solution that I can integrate both.

Comment: Hi. have you managed to find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there are some open tickets for google for this issue, I will wait for using jetpack compose until they solve this problem otherwise for bigger projects it is not eligible to migrate every synthetic binding at once.

Comment: Same here, Compose is unusable without this working. All modern Kotlin projects rely heavily on Kotlin synthetics.

Answer (score -1):

Synthetics [are deprecated](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html) so there is no plan to support them anywhere: you should [migrate to `ViewBinding`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) ASAP (it's not that hard)

But supporting them in Compose actually does not make sense: since Compose is Declarative and not imperative, you don't use ids or any "access method", you probably need to [rethink how to do things with Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model)

Maybe try to explain what you are trying to do exactly ?